# directive isolate scope not triggering $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've got a directive that shares data with its controller, which I'm doing with an isolate scope.

However, when I update the data from inside the directive, neither the directive nor the controller sees the data change using $watch.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.buttonSettings = {
    val: 0
  }

  $scope.$watch('buttonSettings.val', function(val) {
    console.log('watchInController')
    console.log(val)
  });
});

app.directive('buttonTest', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      buttonSettings: '='
    },
    template: '<button>{{buttonSettings.val}}</button>',
    link: function(scope) {
      var button = $('button');

      console.log(scope.buttonSettings)

      scope.$watch('buttonSettings.val', function(val) {
        console.log('watchInDirective')
        console.log(val)
      });

      button.bind('mouseover', function() {
        scope.buttonSettings.val++;
        console.log('mouseover')
        console.log(scope.buttonSettings.val)
      })
    }
  }
});
```

And here's the full example in plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lnztoMhtU03Qzl0BaMpk?p=preview

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not use jQuery that way. Instead of selecting button with jQuery, you can just inject it to your directive using **element** parameter.

Second, you need to use **$scope.$apply** to trigger watches in your directive and controller.

```
app.directive('buttonTest', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      buttonSettings: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.bind('mouseover', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.buttonSettings.val++;
        });
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Check out this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nQUnAKPAB3kkYL5aqLj2?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

halilb is correct that you should not be using jQuery to select element, but instead use the element that Angular provides to your directive, and that `$scope.$apply` is needed in order to register events that occur outside of Angular's context. However, you don't at all need to make a new directive to solve your problem here. Just use Angular's `ngMouseover` directive. You can bind a function to it or just add your logic directly in. Here's a very minimal, simple example.

```
<div ng-init="foo = 1">Value: {{foo}}</div>
<button ng-mouseover="foo = foo+1">Mouse over this: {{foo}}</button>
```

Here's how the same code looks with the logic moved to the controller:

```
<div>Value: {{foo}}</div>
<button ng-mouseover="incrementFoo()">Mouse over this: {{foo}}</button>
```

controller:

```
$scope.foo = 1;
$scope.incrementFoo = function() {
  ++$scope.foo;
};
```

### [Live demo](http://jsbin.com/rujeqe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I do know about ngMouseover - I wasn't using it in the example because I needed a simple way to demonstrate the issue I was having.